# Naming return value in Idris?

Tags: idris

In Idris, one can explicitly name arguments in function type declarations, like

```
length : (str : String) -> Nat
```

But when I try to name the return value, like in

```
length : (str : String) -> (lengthOfStr : Nat)
```

the idris compiler throws an error

> unexpected end of input
>   expecting "->"

Why doesn't the same syntax for naming arguments work for return values? Is there a way to name return values in Idris (so they can be referenced in the doc-string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible, see this [issue](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/1940#issuecomment-75653989). Your question about doc-string might change some opinions, why not ask there? But there might be a problem: someone might think that e.g. `f: (n : Nat) -> (n : Nat)` is valid and would only allow `f n = n` as an implementation. But you can't specify the return value, only the return type.